# Missing ReactInputSelection in react-dom 16.1

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I transferred the project to react 16.1 and there is no ReactInputSelection module anymore in the react-dom.
Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not (and never was) a public API. So importing it is not supposed. Private APIs are not exposed in React 16 anymore.

If you need this file, you can find it in React DOM 15 distribution, and copy and paste it (and any dependencies) directly into your project:

[ReactInputSelection.js](https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/lib/ReactInputSelection.js)